# How to divide data into night time data and day time data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I guys and gals,

I need help with dividing in pandas this dataframe into night time and day time data. Lets assume  the night is after 17:00 and before 08:30 and that the day is between 08:30 and 17:00.

```
Date   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Vol
7   2019-09-02  05:00  11919.9  11929.7  11917.7  11918.9  240
8   2019-09-02  06:00  11920.7  11940.4  11917.7  11927.9  240
9   2019-09-02  07:00  11927.4  11966.2  11927.2  11936.4  240
10  2019-09-02  08:00  11936.9  11955.9  11928.1  11951.4  240
11  2019-09-02  09:00  11951.4  11960.2  11939.4  11954.4  240
12  2019-09-02  10:00  11953.9  11995.9  11951.4  11976.9  240
13  2019-09-02  11:00  11976.7  11979.4  11956.2  11965.9  240
14  2019-09-02  12:00  11966.2  11971.4  11956.4  11965.4  240
15  2019-09-02  13:00  11965.7  11969.7  11943.4  11947.7  240
16  2019-09-02  14:00  11947.4  11962.4  11943.9  11960.7  240
17  2019-09-02  15:00  11960.9  11964.2  11901.2  11934.9  240
18  2019-09-02  16:00  11934.9  11939.7  11921.4  11929.7  240
19  2019-09-02  17:00  11929.9  11940.4  11928.4  11938.2  236
20  2019-09-02  18:00  11937.9  11938.2  11934.7  11938.2  176
21  2019-09-02  19:00  11937.9  11948.7  11937.7  11943.2  196
```

The between_time only shows times for the current date so that alone doesnt do it.

Comment: What would be the output here? Two dataframes?

Comment: What did you try? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Time `17:00` is in day or in night?

Comment: @ 

I tried this but it didnt do the trick
    day = df.between_time('09:00','17:00')
    day = (day.resample('24H', base=9, closed='right', label='right').agg(OrderedDict(ohlc_dict))).dropna()

Comment: @DanEkström - Answer is edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea is convert `Time` column to timedeltas and filter by boolean mask with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
mask = (pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str).add(':00'))
          .between(pd.Timedelta('08:30:00'), pd.Timedelta('17:00:00')))
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
          Date   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Vol
11  2019-09-02  09:00  11951.4  11960.2  11939.4  11954.4  240
12  2019-09-02  10:00  11953.9  11995.9  11951.4  11976.9  240
13  2019-09-02  11:00  11976.7  11979.4  11956.2  11965.9  240
14  2019-09-02  12:00  11966.2  11971.4  11956.4  11965.4  240
15  2019-09-02  13:00  11965.7  11969.7  11943.4  11947.7  240
16  2019-09-02  14:00  11947.4  11962.4  11943.9  11960.7  240
17  2019-09-02  15:00  11960.9  11964.2  11901.2  11934.9  240
18  2019-09-02  16:00  11934.9  11939.7  11921.4  11929.7  240
19  2019-09-02  17:00  11929.9  11940.4  11928.4  11938.2  236

df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
          Date   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Vol
7   2019-09-02  05:00  11919.9  11929.7  11917.7  11918.9  240
8   2019-09-02  06:00  11920.7  11940.4  11917.7  11927.9  240
9   2019-09-02  07:00  11927.4  11966.2  11927.2  11936.4  240
10  2019-09-02  08:00  11936.9  11955.9  11928.1  11951.4  240
20  2019-09-02  18:00  11937.9  11938.2  11934.7  11938.2  176
21  2019-09-02  19:00  11937.9  11948.7  11937.7  11943.2  196
```

EDIT:

Another idea with [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), but necessary `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + ':' + df['Time'].astype(str))
df = df.set_index('Datetime')

day = df.between_time('09:00','17:00')
night = df[~df.index.isin(day.index)]
```

Comment: I like this thinking, especially since night and day can be dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like this, obviously change the times to what you need! but this is the general idea.

```
In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Time":[
    ...: "05:00",
    ...: "06:00",
    ...: "07:00",
    ...: "08:00",
    ...: "09:00",
    ...: "10:00",
    ...: "11:00",
    ...: "12:00",
    ...: "13:00",
    ...: "14:00",
    ...: "15:00",
    ...: "16:00",
    ...: "17:00",
    ...: "18:00",
    ...: "19:00"]})

In [59]: df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]))

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
                      Time
Time
2019-09-15 05:00:00  05:00
2019-09-15 06:00:00  06:00
2019-09-15 07:00:00  07:00
2019-09-15 08:00:00  08:00
2019-09-15 09:00:00  09:00
2019-09-15 10:00:00  10:00
2019-09-15 11:00:00  11:00
2019-09-15 12:00:00  12:00
2019-09-15 13:00:00  13:00
2019-09-15 14:00:00  14:00
2019-09-15 15:00:00  15:00
2019-09-15 16:00:00  16:00
2019-09-15 17:00:00  17:00
2019-09-15 18:00:00  18:00
2019-09-15 19:00:00  19:00

In [61]: df["time_desc"] = "night"

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
                      Time time_desc
Time
2019-09-15 05:00:00  05:00     night
2019-09-15 06:00:00  06:00     night
2019-09-15 07:00:00  07:00     night
2019-09-15 08:00:00  08:00     night
2019-09-15 09:00:00  09:00     night
2019-09-15 10:00:00  10:00     night
2019-09-15 11:00:00  11:00     night
2019-09-15 12:00:00  12:00     night
2019-09-15 13:00:00  13:00     night
2019-09-15 14:00:00  14:00     night
2019-09-15 15:00:00  15:00     night
2019-09-15 16:00:00  16:00     night
2019-09-15 17:00:00  17:00     night
2019-09-15 18:00:00  18:00     night
2019-09-15 19:00:00  19:00     night

In [63]: df.loc[df.between_time("06:30", "18:00").index, "time_desc"] = "day"

In [64]: df
Out[64]:
                      Time time_desc
Time
2019-09-15 05:00:00  05:00     night
2019-09-15 06:00:00  06:00     night
2019-09-15 07:00:00  07:00       day
2019-09-15 08:00:00  08:00       day
2019-09-15 09:00:00  09:00       day
2019-09-15 10:00:00  10:00       day
2019-09-15 11:00:00  11:00       day
2019-09-15 12:00:00  12:00       day
2019-09-15 13:00:00  13:00       day
2019-09-15 14:00:00  14:00       day
2019-09-15 15:00:00  15:00       day
2019-09-15 16:00:00  16:00       day
2019-09-15 17:00:00  17:00       day
2019-09-15 18:00:00  18:00       day
2019-09-15 19:00:00  19:00     night
```

Comment: @DanEkström - So need new column?

Comment: @jezrael It doesnt matter. Sorry, I can see now that the answer below works. The first time I ran the below answer the data was caped at 20:00 but now it works. I must have made a coding error.